# Access manifest.xml data from within the office excel addin TaskPane

Tags: javascript, typescript, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I need to ensure the manifest version is compatible with my taskpane website. To handle it I need to know the currently used manifest version.

I didn't find anything in the API documentation a way to do that. The only way I imagined is to embbed the xml version as a query param for my home URI:

```
<bt:Url id="Home.url" DefaultValue="https://ENV_URL/home?manifestVersion=ADDIN_VERSION" />
```

Is there a better way to do this within the taskPane using Office API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no Office API to fetch manifest.xml data. Embedding the XML version as a query param is the best way.

To suggest this API, please go to [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).